# Java can't find main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I have written the following Java source file (`Hello.java`):

```
package com;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I save this to `C:/tmpjava/Hello.java`.

From the command line, I navigate to that directory and run `javac Hello.java`. Then I run `dir`:

- `Hello.class`
- `Hello.java`

Then, from the same directory that I just ran `javac` from, I run `java Hello.class` and get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: Hello.class.  Program will exit.
```

What's going on here?!? How can `javac` run fine, but not `java`?

Comment: Do NOT specify ".class" when invoking.  Just `java Hello`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your class `Hello` belongs to the package `com`. So the fully qualified name of your class is `com.Hello`. When you invoke a program using java on the command-line, you should supply the fully-qualified class name of the class that contains your `main` method  and omit the *.class*, like so:

```
java com.Hello
```

The java program needs this fully-qualified class name to understand which class you are referring to.

But you have another problem. The java program locates packages, sub-packages, and the classes that belong to them using the filesystem. So if you have a package structure like `com.Hello`, the java program expects to find a class file named *Hello.class* in a directory named *com*, like this: *com/Hello.class*. In fact you can observe this behavior in the `Exception` that you see; you've incorrectly used *Hello.class*, which java is interpreting as a *package* named `Hello`, and a *class* named `class`, and is looking for the directory structure *Hello/class*:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello/class

But the compiler javac **doesn't** set up this directory structure by default. See the [documentation for javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html), but the important bit is this: when you do your compiles, you can specify a destination directory using the `-d` flag:

> -d directory
>
> Set the destination directory for class files. The destination directory must already exist; javac will not create the destination directory. If a class is part of a package, javac puts the class file in a subdirectory reflecting the package name, creating directories as needed. For example, if you specify -d c:\myclasses and the class is called com.mypackage.MyClass, then the class file is called c:\myclasses\com\mypackage\MyClass.class.
>
> **If -d is not specified, javac puts the class file in the same directory as the source file.**

The last bit in bold is the source of much confusion for beginners, and is part of your own problem.

So you have two alternatives:

1. In your case, it's fine if you supply the current directory as the destination directory, like so (the period `.` means *current directory*):

   ```
   javac -d . Hello.java
   ```

   If you invoke the compiler like this, it will create the *com* directory for you, and put your compiled class file in it, the way that the java program expects to find it. Then when you run java as above, from *c:\tmpJava*, your program should execute.
2. You could set up your source code using a directory structure that mirrors your package structure: put your source file *Hello.java* inside a directory called *com*, in your case: *c:\tmpJava\com\Hello.java*. Now, from *c:\tmpJava* you can run your javac compile like this:

   ```
   javac com\Hello.java
   ```

   You haven't supplied the `-d` flag, but that's fine, because you've created the directory structure yourself, and quoting again from the documentation above:

   > If -d is not specified, javac puts the class file in the same directory as the source file.

   Again, when you run java as above, your program should execute.

   Note that this second alternative is one that is commonly employed by java programmers: the source code files are organized in a directory structure that mirrors the package structure.

In this explanation we've ignored the concept of the *classpath*. You'll also need to understand that to write java programs, but in your case of simply compiling a program in the current directory - if you follow one of the two alternatives above when compiling your class - you can get away without setting a classpath because, by default, the java program has the current directory as a classpath. Another quote, this one from the [documentation for java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> -cp classpath
>
> Specify a list of directories, JAR archives, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Class path entries are separated by semicolons (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> **If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, the user class path consists of the current directory (.).**

Note that when you use an IDE like Eclipse to run your java code, this is mostly handled for you, but you'll still run into classpath issues.

Comment: Great answer. Although I knew about these concepts, this was a great refresher

Comment: Thank you! Learning Java and thought for myself "Hey, Eclipse gives me too much for free, lets learn the basics as well", and this was perfect to understand why I couldn't run my program on command line.

Comment: @Gauntlet glad it helped: this has been confusing since the beginning (of java). Still quite a few things to trip over with CLASSPATH, you'll find yourself going back and reviewing the details more than once. Also, if there was anything unclear or outright wrong with this answer, please edit (or comment): it's good to have fresh eyes on the explanation

Comment: Great answer.  As a .NET programmer who has last touched java eons ago, been really stumped on this.  Thanks.

Comment: @sovemp you're welcome glad to see an old answer continuing to help

Comment: @sovemp since you're coming from .NET, I would also recommend that if you're not using an IDE that should manage this for you, you should also dig into the details of setting a _classpath_, especially if you'll be setting up a non-trivial project/build structure outside an IDE. I haven't had to do this in a while, but you should be able to set this as an environment variable in windows

Answer (score 16):

The syntax of the Java command is:

```
java [classname]
```

*not*

```
java [filename]
```

Java looks in its *classpath* for a class of the name you have provided. Usually the classpath includes the current directory, so:

```
java Hello
```

... will find Hello.class in the current directory, and run its main() method.

However, if the class is somewhere else (like in a .jar, or somewhere else in the filesystem) you can specify it with the CLASSPATH environment variable, or on the commandline:

```
java -cp build/classes Hello
java -cp build/jars/myjar.jar Hello
```

Comment: invalid up vote, can't reverse it because it's not really down votable either. ack.

Comment: If you click on the up arrow a second time, it removes your upvote (noble of me to point this out!)

Comment: Nah, I'll leave it :)

Answer (score 4):

The class should be in `C:\tmpjava\com\Hello.class`
And you should run from `C:\tmpjava`: `java -cp . com.Hello`
When you put a class in a package it defines the file structure of the class. I.e. your class which in package `com` should be in folder `com`

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command

```
java -cp . com.Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

java -classpath c:\tmpjava com.Hello