# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when defining a package

Tags: java

The file `Hello.java` :

```
package org;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello world !");
    }
}
```

Is alone in a directory `C:\Users\hj\dev\java` and is compiled using :

```
java Hello.java
```

It generates the file `C:\Users\hj\dev\java\Hello.class` in the same directory.

When I try to run :

```
javac Hello
```

It returns :

> Error: Could not find or load main class .\Hello.class
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\Hello/class

The dir returns :

```
PS C:\Users\hj\dev\java> dir
    Directory : C:\Users\hj\dev\java
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       08/01/2020     16:33            421 Hello.class
-a----       08/01/2020     16:33            126 Hello.java
```

But it works when I remove `package org;` from the source code.

Do you know how to run a class defined in a package ?

Comment: Your directory structure does not match your package structure

Comment: You specify the class your want to load, not the file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096016/java-cant-find-main-class